# Rails Model logic to detect where call originated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, filter, model

I have a working application with a logging system. My logging system however is not well designed, and I am looking for a more elegant solution.

I have a 'History' model that has the following fields `id` `message` and `event`. Whenever there are the following changes:

- Adding or editing a comment
- Adding or editing a task
- Adding or
  editing a contact

Then a record recording this event is created in the `History` table.

Currently, I set the `event` field manually at the point the `History` model is created or updated. Sometimes this is in the controller, sometimes in a model `after_save` filter, the code is scattered around my application.

I am looking for a way to consolidate the setting of the `event` field to perhaps a method in the `History` Model. In order to do that, my `History` model would have detect where the `create` or `update` call originated from.

Is this possible? is there a better, more "rails" like solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, this is the wrong approach to do it.

What you are currently trying to do translates into

1. The event happened
2. A record recording (1) is going to be made
3. When (2) is being tackled, you figure out where the call for (2) originated from

Instead, you need to front-load the capturing of the event type, i.e., capture the data when it is more readily available instead of sherlocking around and detecting it later, something like following:

1. The event happened
2. The record recording (1) is made, and in it an extra parameter is passed for event
3. Now you just saave it.

I think this goes on in line with simple [Spearation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) - Ideally it shouldn't matter to the History model who calls it - it should be able to save the history on its own and the calling method should provide it all the requisite data.